# How can I turn off this shutoff valve

Tags: water, valve

I'd like to turn off the water supply to the washlet for cleaning, possibly without closing it for the entire house. 
I thought it would be easy.
But apparently i'm not able to close this water valve. I managed to spin the central screw, but tightening it apparently does nothing.

Same for the bottom one, either way doesn't seem to close the water. What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a side-view picture of the valve please?

Comment: How many clockwise rotations of the bottom knob did you try? While a ball-valve shuts in a quarter-turn, a gate valve might take many complete 360° turns.

Comment: try running the water while you turn for instant flow feedback; it's a valve and must work...

Comment: Sorry! I didn't receive notifications so i thought no one answered. I think i tried turning to the end, but i'll try again. It's quite stubborn. I'll try with a side photo, but it's quite in a tight spot. And finally, dandavis, it's complicated to run the water as is connected to a washlet. I could try, but i would like to have at least some more information on which thing to turn. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

you may have to move the "bar" to a horizontal position. (cross ways)